# formatting sourcecode in JSON

Tags: json

I'm currently working on a system for plagiarism detection in programming assingments.
For this, I need to send the contents of source code files to a REST endpoint, preferrably as JSON.
Up until now, I used base64 encoding for converting the content of each file which feels kind of wrong and also causes some overhead since submissions can get pretty large.

Example:

```
{
   "assignment":{
      "title":"HelloWorld assignment",
      "submissions":{
         "student #1":{
            "helloworld.java":"cHVibGljIGNsYXNzIEhlbGxvV29ybGQgew0KICAgIHB1YmxpYyBzdGF0aWMgdm9pZCBtYWluKFN0cmluZ1tdIGFyZ3MpIHsNCiAgICAgICAgU3lzdGVtLm91dC5wcmludGxuKCJIZWxsbywgV29ybGQiKTsNCiAgICB9DQp9DQo="
         },
         "student #2":{
            "helloworld.java":"..."
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

Do you guys have a suggestion how to solve this more elegantly?

Comment: Can't you just... send the strings?

Comment: I would gzip it, then base64.  This keeps away from the quoting issue, and minimizes the size.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol no because that would result in invalid JSON since the sourcecode files will inevitably contain quotes, curly-brackets, etc..

Comment: @Beirdo good suggestion, i'll try that

Comment: @MarkusDietrich Then you aren't escaping it correctly. Literally any implementation of `JSON.stringify`, `json_encode` or whatever language you're using will handle escaping for you.